# Triple product identity for the Gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

The well-known reflection formula for the Gamma function relates its values at $z$ and $1-z$ for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, and has the explicit form

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\pi z}}.
\end{equation}

Is there an appropriate generalization of this formula to the case of a triple product? In particular, is there some simplified form of the expression

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(x+y-z)\,\Gamma(x+z-y)\,\Gamma(y+z-x)?
\end{equation}

In the context of a certain calculation in conformal field theory, there are physical reasons to believe that, for $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}$, this expression should factor into a function of the form

\begin{equation}
C(\{x\},\{y\},\{z\})f(x)f(y)f(z),
\end{equation}

where $\{\cdot\}$ denotes the fractional part, and $f$ is some unknown function.

Any and all input is appreciated.

Comment: The proposed factorization doesn't seem to hold true. Choosing $x=y=z=n\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, we find that $f(n)$ for positive integers must take the form $c (n-1)!$ for $c=C(0,0,0)^{-1/3}$, but then choosing $x=n, y=z=1$ we arrive at the false equation $(n-1)!^2(1-n)!=c^3 (n-1)!$. EDIT: unless $C(a,b,c)$ has a pole as $a,b,c\to 0$, which I guess could be the case.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if anything of this sort held. The symmetries of the Gamma function seem rather well-known, and I have not seen anything of this form before (except the obvious special cases using known symmetries, e.g. the Gauss Multiplication Formula)

Comment: Interesting question. I remember very remotely a related quantity, the Virasoro amplitude (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.08855.pdf) which contains the product of three gamma functions.

Comment: Proceeding similarly to the drivation of the Beta function I have found this formula for three variables $\int _0^1\int _0^{1-p}p^{x-1} q^{z-1} (1-(p+q))^{y-1}\;dqdp=\frac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (y) \Gamma (z)}{\Gamma (x+y+z)}$. This can be extended to $n$ variables.